# Scala option variable overrides when string is not empty

Tags: scala, option-type

I have 2 option variables and want to assign 2nd one to 1st one when 1st is None or empty string. Is there a better way writing this? I need to do these for 10 other similar properties in a class.

```
var myoption1: Option[String]
var myoption2: Option[String]

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
  implicit class Addons(val s: String) {
    def isEmptyS = StringUtils.isEmpty(s)
    def isNotEmpty = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s)
  }

if (myoption1.map(_.isEmpty).getOrElse(true) &&
    myoption2.map(_.isNotEmpty).getOrElse(false)
    ) myoption1 = myoption2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care which empty string out of 2 will end up in `myoption1` if both of them are empty, then I suggest this:

```
myoption1 = myoption1.filter(_.nonEmpty).orElse(myoption2)
```

Comment: I know, just thought that StringUtils.isEmpty could contain different logic regarding trimming or whatever. Edited.

Comment: shouldn't it be `filterNot`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz The question is to assign 2nd one to 1st one when 1st is None or empty string.

Comment: @angelokh it was `myoption1.filter(_.isEmpty)` at the time I asked